# how to create a bash script that reads input from a csv file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a csv file as below,

```
No. Of tests,5,,,,
Test#,Test Start Time,JMX name,csv1 name,csv2 name,csv3 name
1,11:30:00 UTC,USM.jmx,FRT.csv,TSG.csv,JSJ.csv
2,13:30:00 UTC,TLB.jmx,HJH.csv,JFG.csv,KSK.csv
3,15:30:00 UTC,TVS.jmx,HGH.csv,JSF.csv,UTY.csv
4,17:30:00 UTC,PLM.jmx,LKI.csv,KYT.csv,NBH.csv
5,19:30:00 UTC,NSC.jmx,GAG.csv,BDG.csv,LKD.csv
6,21:30:00 UTC,BVF.jmx,HAH.csv,DHD.csv,QWE.csv
7,23:30:00 UTC,BVG.jmx,RQR.csv,HDG.csv,RTY.csv
8,01:30:00 UTC,FRE.jmx,RET.csv,HDH.csv,ASD.csv
9,03:30:00 UTC,VFR.jmx,TRD.csv,HDH.csv,ASF.csv
10,05:30:00 UTC,YUY.jmx,YHG.csv,HDG.csv,ZXC.csv
```

I want to run couple of tests as defined in using this csv file.
I want to create a bash shell to run these tests. Pseudo code for the shell is like,

```
for (i=0;i<no. of tests defined in csv's first line;i++)
{
      First loop should be started at time mentioned in first line, second column.
      execute.sh JMX_name1 csv1_name1 csv2_name1 csv3_name1 (pick from the first row)
      (I have this execut.sh)
}
```

How to achieve this, can someone please help. How to save different values of csv in different variables, so that I can use them in loop. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write this:

```sh
(
    IFS=, 
    read -ra ntests
    read header
    for ((i = 1; i <= ${ntests[1]}; i++ )); do
        read -ra test

        # pause until time is ${test[1]}
        # implementation left as an exercise

        execute.sh "${test[@]:2:4}"
    done
) < testing_file.csv
```

Thats grouping all the reads and the loop in a subshell, so the redefinition of IFS does not alter the current shell.